# How to convert treeview to xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I am working on a project currently and I need to convert the treeview to xml so that I can send that xml data to another port.

Comment: Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET,...?

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Windows Form...I am quite new...so I have only done research and I couldnt find any codes

Answer (score 5):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rootElement = new XElement("root", CreateXmlElement(treeView1.Nodes));
    var document = new XDocument(rootElement);
    document.Save("C:\\1.xml");
}

private static List<XElement> CreateXmlElement(TreeNodeCollection treeViewNodes)
{
    var elements = new List<XElement>();
    foreach (TreeNode treeViewNode in treeViewNodes)
    {
        var element = new XElement(treeViewNode.Name);
        if (treeViewNode.GetNodeCount(true) == 1)
            element.Value = treeViewNode.Nodes[0].Name;
        else
            element.Add(CreateXmlElement(treeViewNode.Nodes));
        elements.Add(element);
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: should change to (treeViewNode.GetNodeCount(true) == 0)

Comment: @mcuw:  Not true. If (treeViewNode.GetNodeCount(true) == 0) then treeViewNode.Nodes[0] = null.  Thus, element.Value = treeViewNode.Nodes[0].Name would cause a crash.

Comment: As im populating my treeview with an XML that already has a root note (so my treeview starts with root) this code adds another root every time it exports. Is there some way to skip  a specific node from the treeview (but not its children) or skip the root creation of the export ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   Here is the code snippet :

   public void exportToXml(TreeView tv, string filename)
    {
        sr = new StreamWriter(filename, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        sr.WriteLine("<" + tv.Nodes[0].Text + ">");
        foreach (TreeNode node in tv.Nodes)
        {
            saveNode(node.Nodes);
        }
        //Close the root node
        sr.WriteLine("</" + tv.Nodes[0].Text + ">");
        sr.Close();
    }

    private void saveNode(TreeNodeCollection tnc)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in tnc)
        {

            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                sr.Write("<" + node.Text + ">");
                saveNode(node.Nodes);
                sr.WriteLine("</" + node.Text + ">");
            }
            else
                sr.Write(node.Text);
        }
    }
```