# how to save treenode as xml and load?

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

I tried to save and load treenodes of my treeview,I created tree with list of treenodes as follow:

```
  [Serializable]
public class Tree : List<TreeNode>
{
    public void Save()
    {

       System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Tree));
       System.IO.FileStream s = new System.IO.FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\nodes.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        x.Serialize(s, this);
        s.Flush();
        s.Close();
    }

    public static Tree Load()
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Tree));
        System.IO.FileStream s = new System.IO.FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\nodes.xml", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        Tree tree = x.Deserialize(s) as Tree;
        s.Close();
        return tree;
    }
}
```

Then In the save button I wrote this one:

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SaveButton.Enabled = false;
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        foreach (TreeNode treeNode in this.treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            tree.Add(treeNode);
        }
        tree.Save();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.SaveButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

in the loaded form I used this one:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Tree tree = Tree.Load();
        //Process Tree
        foreach (TreeNode node in tree)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode=new TreeNode(node.Text);


            this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

        }
        //End Process Tree
```

I didn't do anything further and I think nodes.xml is not correct I didn't know what to write there if I want to create the xml file what should I do to make this works?
it has **invalidopeartionexception error**

Comment: Where in your code are you getting this error..? what line or method..?
Try looking at Deserialization here is a good link with source code that will help you in getting started.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13099/Loading-and-Saving-a-TreeView-control-to-an-XML-fi

Comment: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Tree)); in the save method

Comment: I searched that but I want mine to work.it is from a sample that it is working  I just changed some of the code and now it doesn't work

Comment: Was it working before you made the changes..?
Here is another link to look at as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419846/how-to-convert-treeview-to-xml

Comment: Negin, I can paste a simpler example that I have used several times in the past and perhaps you can use that as a way of doing it .

Comment: You cannot serialize a TreeNode - the InnerExceptions of your InvalidOperationException explains that.  You need to serialize the DATA of the tree/nodes - the links DJ Kraze provided help point you to that.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE if you can help me really and it is more simple please show me John ok then how Should I do it? I have a class newNode too which I will get them

Comment: from a menu script when adding my nodes to the tree

Comment: Try reading those two articles - and don't change the code until you actually run and understand those; especially the second link - which honestly doesn't get any simpler.

Comment: yes @DJ KRAZE it is working in another program but it has a list of nodes and a different class node

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler way of doing it the code below is more for converting any object into XML
once you understand this one feel free to try the advanced code when and where needed
[How to convert treeview to xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419846/how-to-convert-treeview-to-xml)

Here is an example of how you can Serialize and Object to XML and Deserialize it I hope this example helps..

**To write any object or some collections to xml Object must have a default constructor.

```
public static string SerializeToXmlString(object objectToSerialize) 
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToSerialize);
    ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
    return ascii.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

**And this should turn the xml back into an object

```
public static object DeSerializeFromXmlString(System.Type typeToDeserialize, string xmlString) 
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeToDeserialize);
    return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: then it should work for treenode? is it considered as an object?