# Populating a tree view from an xml file using only some info

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, treeview

i have an xml file that looks similar to this

```
<items>
    <cla1>
        <type1>
            <unit>this is a unit</unit>
            <title>this is a title</title>
            <link></link>
        </type1>

        <type2>
            <unit>this is a unit</unit>
            <title>this is a title</title>
            <link></link>
        </type2>
    </cla1>

        <cla2>
            <type1>
                <title>this is a title</title>
                <link></link>
            </type1>
        </cla2>

</items>
```

Using this informatoin I wish to populate a treeview control to look like this:

(cant add images so here is a link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlebv.png

```
name of cla
 |____type1 value
 |  |____unit value
 |      |_____title value
 |____type2 value
 |  |____unit value
 |      |_____title value
 |
name of cla
 |____type1 value
 |  |____title value
 |
```

I understand that my xml structure may make this difficult (only new to it) however I dont mind changing this if it makes things easier. Any suggestions on how to accomplish what im looking for would be appreciated. Here's a sample of what I have already, to me this seems excessive and inefficient, I have a feeling that there is a much easier way of doing this.

```
//this code is in a loop going over certain nodes and
//keeps going like this until it reaches the end

if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(cla))
{ treeView1.Nodes.Add(cla, cla); }

if (!treeView1.Nodes[cla].Nodes.ContainsKey(type))
{
treeView1.Nodes[cla].Nodes.Add(type, type);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In your example, in the 2nd block code, you have : `cla -> type1 -> unit -> title` and in the next node: `cla -> type1 -> title` . Is that on purpose or not?

Comment: @Noctis that was on purpose although i probably should have mentioned that 'cla' will be one of 2 values and not actually called cla.

Comment: so, you want to use a nicely typed XML, and then organize it in a different way which will involve code and jumping through hoops to display it in a tree view? I think your question needs some clarification and more examples ...

Comment: @Noctis I dont neccessarily have to use xml i just thought that it might make things easier. I'll add some pictues in to show exactly what I'm after.

Comment: I guess you are aware that the xml is not formed like the tree you want.  In the xml, title is a child of type, while in your tree, title is a child of unit.  (Just in case you were not aware).  Otherwise, it's not too hard to modify the structure, but what a pain.  It would be better for the structure of the xml to be the same as the tree.

Comment: @user1646737 I understand that the xml isn't the best. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it to make what i want?

Comment: I don't have any xml in front of me to play with, but...  you can see that you have to go to the nextSibling in the xml and make that a new child in the tree.  Isn't it something like .GetFirstSibling() or along those lines?

Comment: You can do the other way around. First create your desired treeview structure in a designer and then serialize into XML. Later on you can edit XML file and load it back into the treeview. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033910/how-to-save-treenode-as-xml-and-load

Comment: @SlavaGu So are you saying make a treeview manually then export it to xml, do what i want with it and then just load it back in similarly?

Comment: Yes, you can serialize treeview into XML and then reload it. It's like File/Save and File/Load. See this for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13099/Loading-and-Saving-a-TreeView-control-to-an-XML-fi

Answer (score 0):

You may try to bind TreeView with XMLDatasource as this sample

This is your xml which I have modified a little with title node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
    <cla1>
        <type1>
            <unit>this is a unit</unit>
            <title text="this is a titl1" link="/Default.aspx"></title>
            <link></link>
        </type1>
        <type2>
            <unit>this is a unit</unit>
            <title text="this is a titl2" link="/Default.aspx"></title>
            <link></link>
        </type2>
    </cla1>
    <cla2>
        <type1>
            <title text="this is a titl3" link="/Default.aspx"></title>
            <link></link>
        </type1>
    </cla2>
</items>
```

Then you have to make binding code in aspx part

```
<asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" id="xmlDataSource"  DataFile="App_Data/XMLFile.xml" />

    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="xmlDataSource" >
        <DataBindings>
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="title" TextField="text" NavigateUrlField="link"  />
        </DataBindings>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

The  section for binding only the elements which have properties to bind, such as the **title** element which has **text** and **link** property. And I would have text property value to display in tree view, link property to act like a navigate url so my code becomes like that. For other elements which you don't want to bind properties, you don't have to do anything with them, the tree view will present as your xml dept.

Comment: This looks promising however im not really sure how to implement this in a windows forms app, can you help with that?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice that you develope on Windows app. For Wiondows app., please see in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437713/binding-hierarchical-xml-to-treeview